# Cordova App does not opening in iPad while it is successfully running on iPad simulator with Xcode

Tags: ipad, ios6, ios-simulator

I have been packaging an app that has been build using Cordova (Dev team is somewhere else) and I have just changed the bundle identifier to match our Enterprise Developer license (identifier like xxx.xxx.AppName from yyy.yyy.AppName). The starting point of the app is an html page and it is perfectly working on iPad simulator in Xcode but If I choose iOS device in Xcode (my iPad) only white color screen is shown up for as long as the app is opened and also it doesn't showing any error message (In Safari Developer mode there is no respectable application under my iPad option). What would be the cause. please help me guys...

App Details,
Hybrid app
Target platform is >= iOS 6
Device - iPad (only for iPad) 
Thanks

Comment: I'm am having the exact same situation.  Works great in the simulator, but when it starts up on the device, it shows the cordova icon, then a white screen, and that's where it sits forever.  You can swipe the screen up and down on the device and it bounces just like you'd expect the web view to do.  But the content doesn't load as far as I can tell.  Again, on the simulator, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the Javascript files we were using and one of the file wasn't rendered correctly since it was referenced wrongly. So eventually we found it and correct it. Guys, for Cordova kind of app, if it behaves similarly, just check are there any java script errors then ensure it before proceeding further.